# Is there a probabilistic version of minimax?

Tags: minimax, expectiminimax

How would a probabilistic version of minimax work?

For example, we may choose a move that could result in a very bad outcome, but that outcome might just be extremely unlikely so we might think it would be worth the risk.

Comment: What about Reinforcement learning?

Comment: You might want to look up 'Markov decision process' and how it is used in reinforcement learning. This is probabilistic minimax in essence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is at least one probabilistic version of minimax, which is called [expectiminimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectiminimax). In [expectiminimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectiminimax), in addition to *min* and *max* nodes, there are also *chance* nodes, which perform a weighted sum of the successors, so the probabilities associated with chance nodes must be known. Given that [expectiminimax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectiminimax) assumes the existence of random events (represented by the chance nodes), the decisions are thus based on [expected values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value).

Section 5.5 of the book [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](https://www.cin.ufpe.br/~tfl2/artificial-intelligence-modern-approach.9780131038059.25368.pdf) provides a description of the expectiminimax algorithm, which was introduced by [Donald Michie](http://www.aiai.ed.ac.uk/~dm/) in [Game-playing and game-learning automata](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/240013423_Game-playing_and_game-learning_automata) (1966). The paper [Optimal strategy in games with chance nodes](http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/actacybernetica/edb/vol18n2/pdf/Melko_2007_ActaCybernetica.pdf) (2007) also gives a decent description of the expectiminimax algorithm.